# How to add a comma between numbers using custom modules

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

I have a custom module that creates a function called "Myvlookup" which works similarly to VLOOKUP, but outputs multiple numbers in a single cell. Here is the code:

```
Function MYVLOOKUP(lookupval, lookuprange As Range, indexcol As Long)
Dim r As Range
Dim result As String
result = ""
For Each r In lookuprange
    If r = lookupval Then
        result = result & " " & r.Offset(0, indexcol - 1)
    End If
Next r
MYVLOOKUP = result
End Function
```

This does work, but I was wondering what I can change it so I can add a comma between the numbers. I tried adding it in between the " ", but that created a comma before the first number and was wondering if there was an easier way than adding another line that will get rid of the first comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the comma like you said you tried and add a Mid statement when you set MYLOOKUP:

```
For Each r In lookuprange
    If r = lookupval Then
        result = result & ", " & r.Offset(0, indexcol - 1)
    End If
Next r
MYVLOOKUP = Mid(result,2)
```

This allows you to *not add another line of code*

Another option is too do this, but it's clunkier:

```
For Each r In lookuprange
    If r = lookupval Then
        If result = "" Then result = r.Offset(0, indexcol -1) Else: result = result & ", " & r.Offset(0, indexcol - 1)
    End If
Next r
```

Comment: @HideyukiTerashima - if this solves your issue please mark as answered. If not, let me know what the issue is.

Comment: Thanks @Rory! Good catch. I fixed it. :)